# use 2 dimension array java to store the point(x,y)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program like bouncingBall. but i generated N obstacles in the screen. Each time the ball touch the obstacle, the obstacle disappears and shows up at another random place. i am trying to use 2 dimension array to store the random-gernerated obstacles' point (x,y).

Right now if I input N>50, it gives me outofbound.
But what i want is to store point from (0,0) to (50,50)..what should I do achieve this with 2-dimentional array?

Thanks!

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class BouncingBall { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java BouncingBall N");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
        if (N > 2500) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java BouncingBall N<=2500");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        double[][] myArray = new double[50][50];

        // set the scale of the coordinate system
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1.0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1.0, 1.0);

        // initial values
        double rx = 0.480, ry = 0.860;     // position
        double vx = 0.015, vy = 0.023;     // velocity
        double radius = 0.02;              // radius       
        double x;
        double y;
        double a[] = new double[2];

        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
        StdDraw.filledSquare(0, 0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK); 
        for(int i=0; i <= N; i++){
            x = 2.0*(double)Math.random()-1.0;
            y = 2.0*(double)Math.random()-1.0;
            for   (int  t=0;t <50;t++){ 
                for   (int   j=0;j <50;j++){ 
                      myArray[t][j]= x; 
                      myArray[j][t]= y; 
                } 
            } 
            StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, 0.02);
            }

        // main animation loop
        while (true)  { 

            // bounce off wall according to law of elastic collision
            if (Math.abs(rx + vx) > 1.0 - radius) vx = -vx;
            if (Math.abs(ry + vy) > 1.0 - radius) vy = -vy;
            // clear the background   
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
            StdDraw.filledSquare(0, 0, 1.0); 
            StdDraw.clear(); 

       StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);  

       for(int t=0; t <= N; t++){
           for   (int   j=0;j <50;j++){ 
                 x = myArray[t][j]; 
                 y = myArray[j][t]; 
           } 
        if ((Math.abs(rx + vx) > x - radius)||(Math.abs(ry + vy) > y - radius))
        {  //if the ball touch the square
            vx = -vx;
            vy = -vy;
            if (args.length == 2 && args[1].equals("-d")){
            x = 2.0*(double)Math.random()-1.0;  //new random x
            y = 2.0*(double)Math.random()-1.0;  //new random y
            }else{
                ;
            }
            StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, 0.02);
            }
        else{
            StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, 0.02); //if not touched, keep it.
            }
        }

       rx = rx + vx; 
       ry = ry + vy;

       StdDraw.filledCircle(rx, ry, radius); 
            // display and pause for 20 ms
        StdDraw.show(20); 
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: What lines cause the error? Please show the complete text of the error message.

Comment: can you include the entire compiler error.

Comment: Again, why are you not showing us the text of the error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the user inputs -1 for N, then x and y won't get a value because the loops bodies won't run.

Simple workaround: assign a default value to x and y (0 for example)

```
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives me another issue ArrayOutofBoundIndex at line x = myArray[t][j];

Comment: @jzhong5 I suppose the reason is that N is >= 50 (t loops from 0 to N).

Comment: You are right. I revised it. However. What  i want in this example is store points from 0,0 to 50,50 so there are totally 2500 points... What should i do? I guess i use the 2 dimensional array in the wrong way.

Comment: loop your t from 0 to 50 and you will get 2500 points - not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @jzhong5 As your initial problem is now solved, I suggest you spend a bit of time with a debugger to try to understand what does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize both `x` and `y`:

```
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
```

Your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is occurring because you only define the array to be 50x50

double[][] myArray = new double[50][50];

yet access an index greater than that using `t`:

```
x = myArray[t][j];
```

Comment: I changed it but still not work. This time it gives me OutofBoundIndex at the line

Comment: @jzhong5 can you post the stacktrace please :)

Comment: We keep asking @jzhong for the error messages, but for some reason he keeps refusing to show them.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I already showed it. After I changed it to double x =0 it gives me outofbound. I know the reason is i set N>50. But what i need is to store points from 0,0 to 50,50 so there are totally 2500 points. That's why i said i was doing something wrong with the 2-dimensional array...

Comment: @jzhong5 What Hovercraft means is a proper compile error or exception message, which gives a detailed explanation of the problem, a line number etc. If you read those messages carefully you will have all the information you need to solve the problems by yourself.

Comment: @jzhong: you are paraphrasing the error and not showing us the message itself exactly as the compiler gives to you. If you don't do this, you are making us guess as to what the error is which is not a good thing to do. Especially since you are paraphrasing it **wrong**.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize your local variables, local variables dont get default values

```
   int double x=0.0;
   int double y=0.0;
```

would solve the compiler error.

```
if N>50
  for   (int  t=0;t <50;t++){ 
                for   (int   j=0;j <50;j++){ 
                      myArray[t][j]= x; // ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exection occurs here 
                      myArray[j][t]= y; 
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. However. What i want in this example is store points from 0,0 to 50,50 so there are totally 2500 points... What should i do? I guess i use the 2 dimensional array in the wrong way. Right now if I get n>50, it gives me outofbound

Comment: @jzhong5 obviously if n>50 it'd throw outofbound exception as your array is of size 50